# Create a new handle to printer for printing a bitmap file

Tags: c++, c, windows, printing, gdi+

I am writing a DLL library in visual c++ which has a functtion where a printer handle is passed as a parameter. This printer handle(HDC printer) is being used for printing a text file. Now i want to send another print job(a bitmap file) to the same printer.

Can we create another handle duplicate of existing handle "printer" which i can use to trigger a new print job.

I have tried doing this by creating new handle using PRINTDLG/PRINTDLGEX but i could not succeed

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "ActPlugin.h" //My programs Header file
 #include "stdlib.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <objidl.h>

 #include "QRGenerator.h" // My program's header file

 #include <gdiplus.h>
 #include <GdiPlusGraphics.h>
 using namespace Gdiplus;
 #pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

 bool GetPrinterDC(HDC *Printer)
 {
     // Display the printer dialog box so the user can select the 
     //  printer and the number of copies to print.
     BOOL            printDlgReturn = FALSE;
     HDC             printerDC = NULL;
     PRINTDLG        printDlgInfo = {0};
     LPWSTR          localPrinterName = NULL;
     PDEVMODE        returnedDevmode = NULL;
     PDEVMODE        localDevmode = NULL;
     int             localNumberOfCopies = 0;

     // Initialize the print dialog box's data structure.
     printDlgInfo.lStructSize = sizeof(printDlgInfo);
     printDlgInfo.Flags =
     // Return a printer device context.
     PD_RETURNDC
     // Don't allow selecting individual document pages to print.
     // Remove this flag if you want to support this feature.
     | PD_NOSELECTION;

     // Display the printer dialog and retrieve the printer DC.
     printDlgReturn = PrintDlg(&printDlgInfo);
     // Check the return value.
     if (TRUE == printDlgReturn)
     {
          // The user clicked OK so the printer dialog box data 
          //  structure was returned with the user's selections.
          //  Copy the relevant data from the data structure and 
          //  save them to a local data structure.

          //
          // Get the HDC of the selected printer
          printerDC = printDlgInfo.hDC;
      }

      if (printerDC != NULL)
      {
           return false;
      }

      printer = &printerDC;

      return true;
}
```

With the above function i get below erros

```
virtual printer sdk\sample\actplugin\c++\actplugin.cpp(154): error C2065: 'PrintDlgEx' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files\actmask virtual printer sdk\sample\actplugin\c++\actplugin.cpp(154): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'printDlgInfo'
1>c:\program files\actmask virtual printer sdk\sample\actplugin\c++\actplugin.cpp(154): error C2065: 'printDlgInfo' : undeclared identifier
```

If i give my new printjob to existing handle, the new print job(bmp image) is overlapping with the existing print of text file. Hence i want to create a new print job to the same printer.

I have also checked "CreateDC" function where we would need the printer name or printer port. I actually want my program to be dynamic i.e to get the printer at run time. My DLL will be copied on to multiple systems and should be able to automatically detect the printer connected to the system.
That is why i am trying to create a new duplicate handle with existing handle.

I will be very grateful to you, if you can provide me any inputs to fix this issue.
I am actually new to working with bitmap images and printers.

Thanks
Abhinay

**EDIT**

As craig suggested after including  and moving "stdafx.h" to the first line of code i am able to successfully compile and run the program. The user can now select the printer from the prompt now.

I am building a product and i dont want my user to select the printer twice for the same task. Can anyone let me know if i can create new handle to printer with an existing handle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten `<CommDlg.h>` in your include list. And with the code posted, the *output* parameter should be set via dereference, `*Printer = printDlgInfo.hDC;` once you determine the function succeeded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes now i am able to successfully select the printer. The other mistake i made was "stdafx.h" should be the first line of code in viusal c++. The lines above this header are ignored. But is there any possible i can create duplicate handle from the existing handle to printer and send the new print job ? I am actually developing a product, and i want to give best possible solution. I don't want my user to select the printer twice for one task. Let me know if i can meet my requirement. Thanks in advance.